# Is there a way to have Nebular Window a backdrop shadow?

Tags: angular, nebular, ngx-admin

I have a form inside this window and opening it with `{hasBackdrop: false, closeOnEsc: false}` property makes the background of my web app uneasy to look at.

Please take a look here:
[window without backdrop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wtSa.png).

Now is there a way to add backdrop shadow when hasBackdrop is set to false? I just want to disable the dismiss function on clicking outside not the background shadow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see `NbWindowConfig` there is a property that is `closeOnBackdropClick` with a type of boolean. Use that instead of setting `hasBackdrop` to `false`.